# pandas groupby with strings - return single string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
    ID  Type    Size
0   123 Red     5
1   456 Blue    7
2   789 Yellow  12
3   789 Yellow  4
```

I now want to aggregate by `ID` and take the mean of the `size` for duplicates. However, I wish to only return the same string for `Type`, not concatenate it. I have attempted to capture this using `agg`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [123, 456, 789, 789], 'Type' : ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Yellow'], 'Size' : [5, 7, 12, 4]})

def identity(x):
    return x

special_columns = ['Type']
aggfuncs = {col: statistics.mean for col in df.columns}
aggfuncs.update({col:identity for col in special_columns})
df.groupby(['ID'], as_index=False).agg(aggfuncs)
```

However, this still turns into an array of the repeated string:

```
    ID  Type              Size
0   123 Red                 5
1   456 Blue                7
2   789 [Yellow, Yellow]    8
```

The end result I wanted was:

```
    ID  Type              Size
0   123 Red                 5
1   456 Blue                7
2   789 Yellow              8
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each ID has one corresponding type, this should work

```
# use both ID and Type as grouper
res = df.groupby(["ID", "Type"], as_index=False)["Size"].mean()
res
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `first` function as aggregator:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID').agg({'Type': 'first', 'Size': 'mean'})
```

---

```
    ID    Type  Size
0  123     Red   5.0
1  456    Blue   7.0
2  789  Yellow   8.0
```

Comment: It is probably safer to group by both ID and type, if the values are redundant this doesn't change the result, and this avoids having weird aggregation losing a type in case of different types in the same ID.

Comment: @mozway agreed it's cleaner to add an extra dimension to the grouping; however, it's also more costly. + TC's case may be more complex than this, and grouping by an extra column might yield weird results for other cols